# video playing with paperclip ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I've been having problems playing uploaded videos in my ruby on rails app.

So I am using the `paperclip-ffmpeg gem` to process my videos when uploaded, and I am able to create a thumbnail of the video but I am not able to play the video. When I right click on the video I am able to download and I can play it using the player on my computer but I am not able to play it in my view. Also when I right click on it the options for "play", "skip", etc. are all blocked. Here is my model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :clip, :styles => {
            :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'flv'},
            :thumb => {:geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}
        }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]
    do_not_validate_attachment_file_type(:clip)
end
```

And here is my view:

```
<table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Video</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Caption</th>
                    </tr>
                    <% @video.each do |video| %>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%= image_tag video.clip.url(:thumb) %>
                                <%= video_tag video.clip.url(:medium) %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= label_tag video.title %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= label_tag video.caption %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <% end %>
                </table>
```

I have also tried using the `videojs_rails gem` but I wasn't able to play the video using that either. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out, I've been searching for an answer everywhere but haven't come across one that has worked for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys I finally figured out what was wrong, I needed to specify the `type` attribute in the video tag, also instead of using `flv` format I converted my video to `mp4` with those changes I was able to play the video I had uploaded.

Old tag:

```
<%= video_tag video.clip.url(:medium) %>
```

New tag:

```
<%= video_tag video.clip.url(:medium), controls: true, type: "video/mp4", size: "400x400" %>
```

Hope this helps someone